# Flutter image picker won't show up in Android 10

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

I am a beginner in flutter. I was checking to use image_picker in flutter. But When I tried to check image_picker with my Andorid Phone (10) it won't show up. I don't know what happened, I have added **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"** in AndroidManifest.xml,

still no change, I don't know what to do? Please help me

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
    import 'package:path/path.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _fileimage;

  final _picker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _fileimage != null
                  ? FileImage(_fileimage)
                  : Text('No image selected'),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => _takePicture,
                child: Text('hi'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _takePicture() async {
    final pickedImage = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    // if (pickedImage == null) {
    //   return;
    // }

    File tmpFile = File(pickedImage.path);

    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String path = directory.path;

    final String fileName =
        basename(pickedImage.path); // Filename without extension
    final String fileExtension = extension(pickedImage.path); // e.g.

    tmpFile = await tmpFile.copy('$path/$fileName$fileExtension');
    setState(() => _fileimage = tmpFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: any errors when you debug ?

Comment: any update on it? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I found problem with your code.
You used 'FileImage'  in 'Widget' is required. Because 'FileImage' returns 'ImageProvider', you should use 'Image.file()' instead of 'FileImage'.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _fileimage;

  final _picker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _fileimage != null
                  ? Image.file(_fileimage)
                  : Text('No image selected'),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  _takePicture();
                },
                child: Text('hi'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _takePicture() async {
    final pickedImage = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    // if (pickedImage == null) {
    //   return;
    // }

    File tmpFile = File(pickedImage.path);

    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String path = directory.path;

    final String fileName =
        basename(pickedImage.path); // Filename without extension
    final String fileExtension = extension(pickedImage.path); // e.g.

    tmpFile = await tmpFile.copy('$path/$fileName$fileExtension');
    setState(() => _fileimage = tmpFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to fit to screen width  using Image.file()

Comment: ```Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: FileImage(_fileimage),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      )
```